# Do i split script into two parts for clarity, or create methods for the code the parts share

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script called DoritoSpawner which spawns doritos. In this script i have a method which spawns dorito chips and another one that spawns dorito bags. The script totals 322 rows of code and the methods share around 70 rows. Do i create methods for those 70 rows of code which the two spawner methods share or do i split them into two scripts for more clarity. I code together with a group and in a somewhat serious/professional enviroment called university, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 principles that we (as programmers) should follow - SOLID and DRY ..
in SOLID - the S is single responsibility - something should do 1 task and do it very good - the DRY is "do not repeat yourself" .. thinking about these 2 and then decide - I would refactor the common code into it's own method (maybe using static method in a Utility class) and use that in the 2 classes. It is difficult to say with out seeing code, but that is how I see it.

Comment: Thank you, i think you set me on the right path, have to look up static methods and utility classes though.

Comment: enjoy the learning ! it also makes unit testing easier and can highlite problems much faster.. might be a little more work, but well worth it in the end - happy coding !